# Is it efficient to store embedded resources in C# solution in a *.zip archive?

Tags: c#, embedded-resource, projects-and-solutions

### Heading ##I'd like to add a few dictionaries as an embedded resources into my C# solution (*.dic and *.aff files).

Each dictionary is a simple text file inside, so it can be compressed very well.

Is it efficient to store these dictionaries in a *.zip archive, include archive as an embedded resource into my solution and then extract my dictionaries from archive in runtime? Or are embedded resources compressed by default in an assembly file?

By efficient I meant that the install size would be smaller, and runtime slowdown would not be critical.

Comment: string resources aren't compressed.

Comment: Build 2 assemblies, one with some *.zip file and another one with text file of same size, then compare their size. If they are same, go ahead with implementing decompression. Just remember to use RELEASE mode.

Comment: Efficient in what way? Do you care about install size, or runtime speed?

Comment: By efficient I meant that the install size would be smaller, and runtime slowdown would not be critical. I tried to build assemblies as @Agent_L suggested and it seems like text files aren't compressed at all. So I'll go ahead with decompression

Comment: In most scenarios compression is not only more space efficient, but more speed efficient too. Smaller file read saves more time than decompression wastes.

Answer (score 3):

Yes.

We can see this by adding a 1MB xml file as an embedded resource. The resulting dll will increase by approx 1MB. If we on the other hand zip it before hand, the resulting dll can increase as little a few kb depending on the compression level of the content.